# PDF of product of two random variable with PDFs involving Dirac-delta function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to find the PDF of product of two random variables with the following distributions,

```
       f1 = (t/(T Pi r Sqrt[1-((x1^2)/(r^2))])) + (1-t/T) DiracDelta[x1]; 
domain[f1] = {x1, -r, r} && {T> t > 0, r > 0};
```

f1 is mixed distribution where, x1 follows a continuous distribution with probability t/T and rest of the time(1-t/T) the variable, x1=0.

```
       f2  = (2 F^(2/n)/((a^2) n)) x2^(-(2 + n)/n);   
domain[f2] = {x2, F*(a^-n), Infinity} &&  {a > 0, F > 0, n > 0};
```

I used the TransformProduct function in *MathStatica* to generate the PDF of the product x1*x2

```
f3 = TransformProduct[{f1, f2}, y]
```

I get the following result
[image: pdf of f3]

However, when I integrate f3, I get a numerical result equal to t/T, not 1 whereas both f1 and f2 integrates to 1. I feel like there is missing Dirac-delta in the f3 with area (1-t/T) like the one I have in f1. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a TransformProduct function in Mathematica 10.4.  Are you using (the excellent product) *mathStatica* ?  If so, you should mention that.

Comment: Thanks @JimBaldwin I have mentioned now.

Comment: Upgrade you math: you use the DiracDelta distribution as an atomic measure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function . Unfortunately, that topic in the  article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function is not correctly written .

Answer (score 5):

This is an unusual and interesting question. This is a bit obscured by the many parameters that make it difficult to see the wood for the trees.

**Short Answer**

Your first pdf, which has the `DiracDelta` function, is a mixed discrete / continuous random variable. To make this clear, if say $r = 1$, $t = 1$ and $T = 2$, then your mixed pmf/pdf `f1` is:

```
    f1 = 1/(2Pi Sqrt[1-x1^2]) + DiracDelta[x1]/2
```

This is just a weighted average mix of an ArcSine random variable and 0. It could alternatively (and perhaps more naturally) be written as:

```
    f1 = If[ x1 == 0, 1/2, 1/(2Pi Sqrt[1-x1^2])]
```

which would be plotted as:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/mixeddiscretecontinuousArcSine.png))</sub>

By contrast, the `TransformProduct` function states in the Help system:

```
   `Density f and density g can be continuous or piecewise continuous.`
```

This defn does not include *mixed cont/discrete* random variables.

Using a `DiracDelta` function is an interesting way of trying to express a discrete model in a continuous space, but I am not sure that it is appropriate. One cannot even seem to plot it appropriately, though `Integrate` works.

Even though your mixed cont/discrete model is 'incompatible' with the restriction to continuous variables, all is not lost! One can easily provide a workaround, simply by formulating the problem slightly differently ...

**Full Answer**

Let us deconstruct your $X_1$ random variable back to its separate continuous and discrete parts. Then:

$$ X_1 = \begin{cases}0 & \text{with probability } p \\ Z & \text{with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$

where $p = \frac{t}{T}$, and random variable $Z$ has pdf $f(z)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/symmArcSinpdf.png))</sub>

Next, $X_2$ has pdf, say $f_2(x_2)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/hosscustompdf.png))</sub>

The desired product of random variables is:

$$ Y = X_1 X_2 = \begin{cases}0 & \text{with probability } p \\ Z*X_2 & \text{with probability } 1-p \end{cases}$$

Then, the mixed pdf of $Y$ is:

$$ \text{pdf}(Y) =  \begin{cases}p & \text{if } y = 0 \\  (1-p) h(z * x_2)  & \text{if } y \neq 0 \end{cases}$$

where $h(z * x_2)$ denotes the pdf of the product $Z X_2$. The latter ($Z$ and $X_2$) are both continuous random variables, so you can use the `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package to find that $h(z * x_2)$ is:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/productarcsincustom.png))</sub>

... and we are all done.

Here is a plot of $h(.)$ (the continuous part) when  $F=1$, $n = 1$, $a = 2$, $r=1$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/batmangoesmathematical.png))</sub>

All that happens when you embed $h(.)$ into the mixed model $\text{pdf}(Y)$ above is that the continuous density gets scaled down by $(1-p)$, and there will be a discrete mass $p$ at 0.

Comment: Thank you very much @wolfies. I appreciate the help!

Comment: See my comment to the question.